# How to rotate 180 deg a fontawesome icon?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

can any one tell me that how can i rotate a font awesome icon 180 degree. Actually i want to use a truck icon which is directed to right side but i found it left side rotated.

```
For ex:- <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
```

Comment: [The `rotate()` CSS function defines a transformation that rotates an element around a fixed point.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

Comment: seriously ? is it difficult to first ask google ? ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This helped me:

```
.fa {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `transform` css to achieve this:

```
.fa {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

Comment: yes it will work, try this, you can add browser prefixes if you want

Answer (score 2):

Just add the class 'fa-rotate-180'

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the `transform` css option combine it with `rotate()` function.
>   [See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/4zrnghpq/4/)

Comment: that example does not do anything

Comment: @Butri it actually does! It rotates the icon with CSS. Go to the CSS tab and comment out the code to see the difference